# Runing this commend npm run prod

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

when I run npm run prod I got the error at the same time when I run npm run dev it's working fine.so please help me how can I solve this!

```
vendor.js?id=cca30691bc76ccdc077d:1 TypeError: o is not a function
at e (vendor.js?id=cca30691bc76ccdc077d:1:707685)
at a.__patch__ (vendor.js?id=cca30691bc76ccdc077d:1:708574)
at e._update (vendor.js?id=cca30691bc76ccdc077d:1:680721)
at a.r (vendor.js?id=cca30691bc76ccdc077d:1:715665)
at On.get (vendor.js?id=cca30691bc76ccdc077d:1:664809)
at On.run (vendor.js?id=cca30691bc76ccdc077d:1:665452)
at Gt (vendor.js?id=cca30691bc76ccdc077d:1:656164)
at Array.<anonymous> (vendor.js?id=cca30691bc76ccdc077d:1:659995)
at dn (vendor.js?id=cca30691bc76ccdc077d:1:659470)
```